# Openpyxl write in excelsheet cells skipping the first row

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to write in the first two columns row by row, skipping the first row (header). How do I write in the next row everytime I rerun the for-loop?

Right now it just overwrites the 2. row when I run the code in another for-loop.

```
                    wb_master = load_workbook(path_masterlist,keep_vba=True)
                    ws_master = wb_master['sheet1']

                    for cols in ws_master.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col= 2):
                        cols[ws_master.max_row -2].value = "value1"
                        cols[ws_master.max_row -1].value = "value2"
                    wb_master.save(path_masterliste)
                    wb_master.close()
```

Comment: `for row in ws_master.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=2): c1, c2 = row; c1.value="value1"; c2.value = "value2"`

Comment: I dont know how to understand your code correct sorry. if ";" is supposed to be the next line it doesnt work this way